# ES6 class field arrow functions scoping problem

Tags: javascript, function, this, arrow-functions

I assigned my arrow function to outside variable.But I did not understand why this is refer to 'Animal' constructor. When I called function 'fun' it printed
'Animal, true'. But I thought it would print 'Window, false'.

```js
function Animal() {
  this.sleep = () => {
    console.log(this, this instanceof Animal)
  }
}

let animal = new Animal();
animal.sleep(); // Animal, true

let fun = animal.sleep
fun = animal.sleep;
fun() // Animal, true -- why?
```

Comment: @NeelRathod OP means "Original Poster"

Comment: @ArupRakshit  Thanks for sharing a information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions resolve `this` [*lexically*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping), just like any other variable. That means the value of `this` does *not* depend on how the function is *called*, but how/where it was *defined*.

The `sleep` function is defined inside the `Animal` constructor function, which is called with `new`. Therefore `this` will refer to a new instance of `Animal`.